# How to implement <li> and last-class in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a page a top level menu bar that's working fine.  I use a CSS class of #nav for the top menu bar.

I'm trying to implement a second-line menu bar that will contain just two items:  Back and Home.  I'm trying to get the second menu item to float right.  I'm trying to use last-child to do so, but I can't get last-child last-of-type to work.

```css
#nav_row2 {
    position:fixed; /* used to render menu bar fixed on top and not scroll up ALSO ALLOWS MENUS TO STAY ON TOP OF SLIDESHOW*/
}

#nav_row2 li {
    background-color: #BDB76B; /* menu background color */
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left; /* For the menu buttons to float left */
    width:150px; /* Width of the buttons */
    line-height:25px; /* this is the text height of the menu items */
    margin-left:140px; /*Left margin to line up with the parent menu line */
    margin-right: 0; /* */
    list-style-type:none; /* no underscores, etc. */
}

#nav_row2 li:last-child {
    float:right; /* For the menu button to float right */
    margin-left: 0; /* */
    margin-right:140px; /*Right margin to line up with the parent menu line */
}
```

```html
<div style="clear:both" ></div>
    <br />
      <ul id="nav_row2">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)">Back</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.saintsusanna.org/">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    <br />
<div style="clear:both" ></div>
```

Comment: Do you want both home and back to align right? Or Back on the left and Home on the right?

Comment: If you insert your code above in a code snippet you'll notice your `nth` selector is in fact working. Have you inspected the element in browser to verify that there are no other elements, like an arbitrary `br`, being placed in your unordered list?

Comment: There is no closing slash on <br>. Don't use <br> as a replacement for margin in CSS.

Comment: Hi Rachel.  I'd like Back on the left and Home on the right.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `<li>`, you can use the flex box model.

```css
#nav {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  height: 64px;
}
#nav-2 {
  background-color: cyan;
  height: 64px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
span {
  background-color: #BDB76B; /* menu background color */
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left; /* For the menu buttons to float left */
    width:150px; /* Width of the buttons */
    line-height:25px; /* this is the text height of the menu items */
    margin: 0px 16px;
    list-style-type:none; /* no underscores, etc. */
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  Stuff here
</div>
<div id="nav-2">
  <span>home</span>
  <span>back</span>
</div>
```

By altering the margins you can control how far from the side of the box the items are.

Data about the flex box design [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and the MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Answer (score 0):

- Removed floats because they break easily.
- Added `position:absolute` to each li
- Assigned `left: 0;` and `top:0` for all li
- Then used a sibling selector to change the last li's position:

  li + li { right:0; left: initial; }

This ruleset says:

> If there's two sibling li's change add `right:0` rule to the "younger"* sibling and change `left:0` to `left: initial` (by default I believe the initial is actually `left:0`, but I really wanted to show that if inheritance of unwanted properties and/or values can be handled with `initial` in certain circumstances.)

*I use the term "younger sibling" when referring to the sibling node/element that *follows* and I use the term "older sibling" when referring to a sibling that is positioned previously(before) the target node.

Added

```css
#nav_row2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 350px;
}
#nav_row2 li {
  background-color: #BDB76B;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
li {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
li + li {
  right: 0;
  left: initial;
}
```

```html
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<br />
<ul id="nav_row2">
  <li><a href="http://www.saintsusanna.org/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="history.go(-1)">Back</a>
  </li>

</ul>
<br />
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks zer00ne.  I tried this, but changed the width from 350px to 875px. I still have a small problem.  The buttons show on either side of the 875px which is great, but they float on the left side when the screen is resized.  I have a first menu row with six buttons on it. The CSS for the first row has: width:100%; margin-left: -50px; position:fixed;.  The page width is 1000px.  How do I make the 2nd row float in the middle like the top row when the browser window is expanded and contracted?

Comment: No problem @user3138025. If you want to still use floats, it's going to be a painful experience to say the least. If you go with `position`, it's good in small doses, but if used too much, you'll end up using `positions` on everything which would in turn be a nightmare to deal with. I suggest that you use flexbox with a touch of `position` property.

Comment: If your'e interested in flexbox, read up on it little, then work on your problem using flexbox. If you have another problem, (which you most likely will, because it's features are somewhat difficult to grasp at first.) make sure you post a [mcve] like you did with this question. If I don't answer your flexbox question Micheal_B definitely will.

Comment: Hello zer00ne.  I created a new HTML file and a new posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418788/how-to-center-a-menu-using-flexbox  Thanks again for all your help